# Is there a web based Craigslist reader?

Tags: webapp-rec, craigslist

Before you all say "Yeah, Craigslist.com"...

I'm looking for a site that takes information/postings from CL, and give you the ability to do more powerful searches, maybe displays preview images, and/or the other million things Craigslist should do to make their site more useful.

Oh being able to search multiple cities (ie: San Diego, Orange County, Los Angeles) but not ALL of CL would be sweet too.

site:craigslist.org on google is not an acceptable answer!

Comment: +1, but keep in mind that Craigslist does everything they can to shut down these kinds of apps, so most of them are pretty short lived.

Comment: @Eric - interesting, I hadn't realized that. What are there motives for shutting them down? Shame they can't redirect the resources used to shut them down into improving CL!

Comment: @tobeannounced - Seems they just have control issues over their data (understandable I guess, it's their site).  They seem to like the site just as it is and feel like adding anything in the way of features just makes more people angry than happy.

Comment: @Eric @tobeannounced If you want more details on why Craiglist is such a mess, read this: http://www.wired.com/entertainment/theweb/magazine/17-09/ff_craigslist

Comment: @Eric I was under the impression that CL announced their "API" was cURL.

Answer (score 3):

You might take a look at http://craiglook.com/.

It has some of the features you mentioned, but probably not all.  To me, the site is a little too "busy."  I tend to favor the simplicity of Craigslist.  (Though, like you said, there are some features that would be nice to use that Craigslist does not currently offer.  I'd definitely be interested in other sites based on Craigslist.)

Comment: Then vote the question up!

Comment: very cool, especially the location-agnostic searches - unfortunately they don't support CL outside of the US yet (Canada) but according to their uservoice site, its (eventually) planned.  Really just a fancy Yahoo Pipes frontend.

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution which seems to work the best:

http://www.searchtempest.com/

Other notables:

http://craigspal.com/

http://craiglook.com/ (As mentioned by bporter)

http://picclick.com/

Also here is some actual desktop software for searching the CL: 
http://www.fileguru.com/downloads/craigslist_browser

Answer (score 1):

Ping.me notifies you when someone posts a new ad that interests you. You can sort by read / unread. Once you adjust your settings you no longer have to do any manual searches :) http://www.ping.me/

Answer (score 0):

You could probably create a google custom search - I can't remember what they call it, but you can configure a search to just search a subset of sites - sort of like what you get if you search http://google.com/microsoft/

Answer (score 0):

I use the "CraigsPro Free" app on my iPhone.

You can save searches, see thumbnails in results lists, and search multiple cities (results are grouped by city, not mixed).

Haven't used this feature, but apparently you can post to Craigslist from this app as well.

Answer (score 0):

For rentals, and nothing else, http://padmapper.com is a great example of using CL to make awesomeness.